# Is it a good practice to have all your tables connected to each other

Tags: sql-server

This is the first databse I've ever designed and just looking at some other peoples diagrams they all seem to have a relationship to each other. What I mean by that when lookin at my database is that while the vendors table and the Invoices table have a relationship, they are separate from the other 3. Is this bad practice. Should I find a way to relate them?   [image]

Comment: Unless a vendor was providing support for a book issued or a book was provided by a vendor, as weird as that may be, I don't see a needed relation there.  There is no requirement that all tables in a database be interconnected, however, in order to achieve the 4th form of normalization and to promote referential integrity, most are.

Comment: are Invoices sent to Members? do Invoice Positions refer to Issued Books?

Comment: @RossBush But is it required to reach the 4th Normal form, or is it just that most are?

Comment: @Morph 4th normal form doesn't exist without joined tables, however, having un-joined tables does not invalidate 4NF either. The entities in the relationships above specifically invoice and books, do not directly relate, I see no need to join them. If you added, for example, a Library table, then you may the want to create a LibraryMember table or a LibraryVendorInvoice table.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky, but the goal is to get your schema to reflect the natural relationships that exist in the real world things your database represents. You do want to look for relationships that exist and you might have missed, but you don't want to "come up with" relationships that don't exist just for the sake of connecting tables.

You want your tables to have no more and no fewer connections than the entities they are modeling.

It's a subtle distinction, and one that lends itself more to experience and intuition than to a quick rule, so plan on spending a lot of time thinking and revising for your first dozen databases. But think about it and you'll definitely develop the intuition.

While they won't "Give you the answer", there are some things that can help guild your inspection.

Look for repeated values in a table and consider breaking them out to a connected table. Don't go overboard, most applications don't need "Yes" and "No" to be in a linked table, but you might find Publisher should be in a table of its own. I say "might" because if all you ever do is print it on a card then maybe it's OK to have it just a field in the Books table. But you can't easily put it in a drop down selector if it's not in it's own table.

Look for values that appear in 2 different tables, are they actually shared (and belong in a separate table linked to both of the original tables).

Look for fields you might want to enter multiples of. Think how much better contact lists got when designers stopped making "Phone" a field (then 2 fields, then 3 fields) in the "Person" table and made them entries in a linked "Phone" table that supports a many  to one relationship.

Consider how you might present the user with a form to enter your data. If you are tempted to provide a drop down selector, it probably gets populated from a linked table.

Consider what might sound crazy if you tried to put both on a report - if you can't think of a report that contained both vendor bills and books, then the tables probably shouldn't be linked. If you can think of a connection through some common other thing, then the 2 original tables shouldn't be linked directly but maybe should share links with a 3rd table.

As others pointed out in the comments, this is part of the larger issue of Normalization and guidance there will help a lot. Don't put your design on hold while you go learn all about normalization, but think about it in that context.

Make sure you revisit your design with a critical but not judgmental eye when you're done with the project, it will help train that intuition. Good luck!